# Adaptar imagen a carousel bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Hola tengo un problema con el carousel de `bootstrap`.
Quiero que mi carousel tenga  **carousel-inner** `height: 300px;` pero las imagenes no se adaptan al tamaño **carousel-item img** `width: 100%; max-height: 460px;` 
En [este](https://codepen.io/lStevenm/pen/zLMqOp) link esta mi codigo.

```css
.container-fluid{
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;

 }
 
 .carousel-inner img {
  
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 460px;
}

.carousel-inner{
 height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="https:/https:/maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container-fluid bg-primary">
  <div class="row bg-dark">
    
 
<!-- ================== 1-carousel bootstrap  ==================  -->
<div id="carousel1_indicator" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel1_indicator" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel1_indicator" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel1_indicator" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>  
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://picsum.photos/750/400/?random" alt="First slide"> 
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://picsum.photos/750/400/?random" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://picsum.photos/750/400/?random" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel1_indicator" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel1_indicator" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div> 


   </div>
   
</div>
```

Comment: si el height de tu .carrusel-inner es estático y siempre es 300px porque no dejas las imágenes igual siempre a 300px?

Comment: Es mala practica estar mezclando versiones de Bootstrap, hay que definir si vas a trabajar con la 3.7 o la 4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El elemento **carousel-inner** de `bootstrap` responde al tamaño de los elementos que se encuentran dentro de el. En este caso, tu le estas asignando una imagen con `width: 100%` y `max-height: 460px`, pero forzando a **carousel-inner** a estar a `height: 300px`. Lo que esta sucediendo es que la imagen, al tomar el 100% del ancho del div, esta sobrepasando los 300px que le asignaste a **carousel-inner**. Debido a que **carousel-inner** es un elemento responsive, te sugiero que cambies la propiedad de esta forma `.carousel-inner img {height: 300px;}` Además, que limpies el exceso de scripts en tu código. Solo necesitas un link para jQuery, el .css y el .js de Bootstrap. El uso de versiones distintas puede llevar a conflictos en el código

```css
.container-fluid {
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
}

.carousel-inner img {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid bg-primary">
  <div class="row bg-dark">

    <!-- ================== 1-carousel bootstrap  ==================  -->
    <div id="carousel1_indicator" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel1_indicator" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel1_indicator" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel1_indicator" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/750/400/?random" alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/750/400/?random" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/750/400/?random" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel1_indicator" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel1_indicator" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>


  </div>

</div>
```